# Update second view controller in NSSplitViewController

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nssplitviewcontroller

I have a `NSSplitViewController` in which `first viewcontroller` displays a table and `second viewcontroller` should display a viewcontroller from a list of viewcontrollers based on the selection of table row.

[image]

I'm using `tableViewSelectionDidChange()` to get the selected row.

Now I have a bunch of viewcontrollers(storyboard ID given as row number) that I should add and remove to `second viewcontroller` in `NSSplitViewController`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right path.
Within `tableViewSelectionDidChange()` you need to instantiate a new viewController from your storyboard using `NSStoryboard`s `instantiateController(withIdentifier: String)` method. Then you can set this as your splitViews second view controller.

Then you need to create a `splitViewItem`. You can use the init method which takes a viewController for this (`NSSplitViewItem(viewController:)`).

Finally you have two possibilities to add the new viewController. 
Either you use the `add/removeSplitViewItem` methods or you set the `splitViewItems` array directly.

My words in code:

```
guard let splitViewController = self.parent as? NSSplitViewController,
      let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier") as? NSViewController
        else { return }

let item = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: viewController)

// Method one
splitViewController.removeSplitViewItem(splitViewController.splitViewItems[1])
splitViewController.addSplitViewItem(item)

// OR method two
var items = splitViewController.splitViewItems
items[1] = item
splitViewController.splitViewItems = items
```

Comment: It works! But there's a small mistake in the method two. Change `parent` to `splitViewController`.

Comment: This is great, thanks! One question: why not just add the new VC like so: `splitViewController.splitViewItems[1] = item`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an AppKit bug but if I assign the same item twice using `splitViewController.splitViewItems[1] = item` (eg if the user clicks the same table row twice) the split view disappears. Using "Method one" resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C representation of the first method.

```
NSStoryboard * mainStoryboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NSViewController * sourceViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:identrifier];

NSSplitViewItem * item = [NSSplitViewItem splitViewItemWithViewController:sourceViewController];

[self removeSplitViewItem:[self.splitViewItems objectAtIndex:1]];
[self addSplitViewItem:item];
```